# Why isn't the third property in the definition of vector bundles redundant?

Tags: manifolds, definition, examples-counterexamples, vector-bundles

I am studying Manifold theory and it is essential for me to know vector bundles.The usual definition of vector bundles as given in the standard texts is a follows:

Suppose $M$ is a topological manifold and $E$ is another topological manifold with a surjective continuous map $\pi:E\to M$.Then we say $E$ is a vector bundle of rank $k$ over $M$ if the following properties are satisfied:

$1.$ For each $p\in M$ the fiber $E_p=\pi^{-1}(p)$ is a $k$-dimensional vector space.

$2.$(Local Trivialization)For each $p\in M$ there exists an open nbhd $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that there is a homeomorphism $\varphi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb R^k$ such that $\pi_1\circ \varphi=\pi$ ( $\pi_1:U\times \mathbb R^k\to U$ being the projection map onto $U$.)

$3.$ For each $q\in U$,the map $\varphi|_{E_q}:\pi^{-1}(q)\to \{q\}\times \mathbb R^k\cong\mathbb R^k$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Then spaces $E$ and $M$ are referred to as the total space and the base space and $\pi:E\to M$ is called the bundle map/projection.

I am not quite satisfied with the conditions in this definition.Being a beginner I am curious about whether all of these conditions are needed or we can drop some of them as they might be redundant.My doubt centres around the first and the third conditions.In the first condition we are already saying that each fiber lying over some point is a copy of $\mathbb R^k$ but in the third condition,we are again saying that the map $\varphi|_{E_q}:E_q\to \{q\}\times\mathbb R^k$ is a vector space isomorphism.So,given the third condition,the first one should be automatically implied.I do not understand why at all we are putting the first condition then?

This is a source of dissatisfaction in my understanding of vector bundles.Can someone give me examples to show that both $(1)$ and $(3)$ are essential by giving examples where one of them holds and the other doesn't.Looking eagerly to my MathStackExchange folks for answers and suggestions.

Comment: Simply being a vector space versus having an already built-in map that defines an isomorphism with the standard structure are different conditions.  If anything, the first is redundant from the third.

Comment: @Randall So why can't we omit the first condition?

Comment: Maybe we could.  I don't think too much about it.

Comment: @Randall But the question is just about that,can we eliminate the first condition without allowing any anomaly?

Comment: @Randall So,I am seeking a definite answer to ensure whether I have understood the definition properly.

Comment: I understand what you're asking.  Someone will come along and give a great answer.  That person isn't me.

Comment: without the first condition, the third doesn’t even make sense, i.e, the first is just being explicit so that the third makes sense.

Comment: I think your version of the definition is indeed problematic. 1. by itself doesn't make much sense as a property because you can turn any set of the right cardinality into an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. And 3. by itself doesn't make much sense because what is $\varphi$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes,you are right!I overlooked that thing.Without any mention of condition $(1)$ we have no vector space structure on $E_q$,and hence being vector space isomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$ does not make sense.

Comment: @Stefan $\varphi$ can be defined anyway $\varphi :\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb R^k$ is an isomorphism such that $\pi_1\circ \varphi=\pi$.That is not the exact problem to be precise.

Comment: [[0]] It is a valid & nice question +1 [[1]] I can compare it with (Eg) 9 axioms for real numbers which are satisfied by rational numbers & real numbers , then the author adds axiom 10 which is not satisfied by rational numbers & hence it is not redundant & it required for real numbers [[2]] Here too, we have to see what we get with only Criteria 1+2 & what we get with only Criteria 2+3 to then check what we get with Criteria 1+2+3. [[3]] Currently , the Definition looks a little incomplete [[4]] You should include the Exact Definition you have in your textbook , to avoid confusion & ambiguity

Comment: @KishalaySarkar I don't understand what you mean by "can be defined". Surely the $U$ and $\varphi$ in 3 are in some sense referring to the variables introduced in 2. But as stated this is ambiguous. Should every pair $(U,\varphi)$ that satisfies the condition of 2 also satisfy 3 or is it enough that there exists one pair that satisfies 2 and 3?

Comment: @Stefan I had a small typo,was that your source of confusion?

Comment: @Stefan Now it has been corrected.

Comment: I do not understand the question. It is clear that (1) and (2) do not imply (3) (not every homeomorphism of vector spaces is linear), while (3) makes no sense if you do not require (2). What else is there to be clarified? Incidentally, I do not particularly like this axiomatics and personally prefer to replace (1) with the condition on transition maps, requiring $\psi\circ \phi^{-1}$ to be linear on each $\{x\}\times R^k$.

Comment: No, my "source of confusion" is exactly what I wrote. But I don't want to force a discussion on you if you think your definition is fine.

Comment: Or, maybe, you are asking about existence of topological bundles with fibers homeomorphic to $R^k$ which do not admit structure of vector bundles?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "fiber bundle of rank $k$". There are "fiber bundles with fiber $\mathbb{R}^k$", which is what you get when you only demand condition 2. in your post, and also "vector bundles of rank $k$", which appears to be what you are trying to define, but your definition is not correct (as Stefan has pointed out: 1. is an additional datum, not a condition, and condition 3. has to be combined with condition 2.).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the assumption that $M$ and $E$ are manifolds is too strong: There are many reasons to consider vector bundles over topological spaces which are not manifolds. Second, once you assume that $M$ is a topological manifold, Property 2 will imply that $E$ is a manifold as well. Thus, in what follows, I will not assume that $M$ is a manifold, it is totally irrelevant for the discussion.

Now, let's start with Property 2 instead of Property 1: It says that $E\to M$ is a (locally trivial) fiber bundle with fibers homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^k$. However, if we consider "transition maps" for pairs $(U, \varphi), (V,\psi)$, namely, maps
$$
\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}: (U\cap V)\times {\mathbb R}^k\to 
(U\cap V)\times {\mathbb R}^k,
$$
Property 2 only ensures that for all $x\in U\cap V$,
$$
\theta_{x}=\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}: \{x\}\times {\mathbb R}^k \to \{x\}\times {\mathbb R}^k
$$
is a homeomorphism that does not preserve, a priori, any further structure on the vector space $\{x\}\times {\mathbb R}^k$.

The point of Properties 1 and 3 is to ensure that the "transition maps" $\theta_x$ are linear. My personal preference is to replace Properties 1 and 3 by a single condition:

Property 13: For all $(U, \varphi), (V, \psi)$ and $x\in U\cap V$, the maps $\theta_x$ as above are linear.

This allows one to equip each fiber $E_x$ with the structure of a vector space via transfer of the structure using the homeomorphism  $\varphi^{-1}: \{x\}\times {\mathbb R}^k\to E_x$. Property 13 implies that this structure of a vector space is independent of a "chart" $(U, \varphi)$. With this approach, the collection of "charts" $(U, \varphi)$ becomes a part of the data of a vector bundle (just like an atlas with smooth maps is a datum defining a differentiable structure on a topological manifold).

Now, back to Properties 1 and 3. Property 1 is badly stated, it should be formulated as

"Each $E_x$ comes equipped with the structure of a vector space."

Note that the dimension $k$ assumption is irrelevant here (it is a consequence of Property 2). What's important is the fact that such a vector space structure on the fibers is a **part of the data** of a vector bundle (just like the map $\pi$ is a part of the bundle data). If one omits Property 1, then Property 3 simply does not make sense since you **cannot** talk about a linear isomorphism between two spaces, one of which is just a topological space homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^k$ (in view of Property 2) and the other is ${\mathbb R}^k$. Now, if you omit Property 3, then Property 1 contains no information (besides one which is already in Property 2); if one uses Property 1 as a part of a vector bundle data, the vector space structures on the fibers $E_x$, a priori, vary discontinuously and, hence, this datum is useless for topological purposes. The point of Properties 1 and 3 combined is to ensure that fibers $E_x$ have structure of vector spaces (Property 1) which "depends continuously on $x$" (this is what Property 3 formalizes).

One last thing: One can ask if Property 2 alone implies existence of a vector bundle structure on a topological bundle satisfying Property 2. This turns out not to be the case, as follows, for instance, from

*Browder, William*, [**Open and closed disk bundles**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970428), Ann. Math. (2) 83, 218-230 (1966). [ZBL0148.17503](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0148.17503).